# How to degrade the program to lower android version?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have developed an app for android 8.0 and it is working smoothly in android 8.0. But I am getting "Parse error – there is a problem parsing the Package" in android 4 & 5(I have not checked it for 6 and 7, consider this error is coming for the lower than android 8.0.). I am using bottom navigation bar in my app. I think it works for android 4 and above. But still getting the error.
My Question is can I degrade my program from android 8.0 to android 4 and above so that my app will work for all the mobiles having android version greater than or equal to 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should configure your build.gradle file to suit the requirements. For example the min sdk version. For more info refer https://developer.android.com/studio/build.

And then AppCompat will do the rest. But you have to keep in mind that AppCompat is not fully fledged as some versions will be supported and some will have minor defects.